# Data storage best practice mobile application

Tags: xamarin, translation, mobile-development

I am a junior Android Developer and I intend to develop a little cross platform with Xamarin.

This app is just a FAQ with an enormous amount of data which will not change in the time (additionally I would like to add a quiz). I want the app be multilingual and be accessible without Internet Connection.

My worry is about the choice of the method of storage of the data and the handling of translation. Which method should you recommend?

Comment: Why not plain text (or HTML) files?

Comment: So Doing this app with HTML with eventually embedded JS would be great ? Would you recommend me Ionic or React Native ?

Comment: you asked about how to store the data, not which framework to use

Comment: I assume the choice of way of storing data will imply to target a couple of frameworks which will be more likely to solve the problem I faced.